# Java ClassLoader Issue or Concurrency Error?

Tags: java, weblogic, classloader, static-initializer

After a WebLogic app has been running fine for a few weeks I suddenly get an Exception:

```
<Oct 25, 2014 9:31:11 PM EDT> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101020>
    <[ServletContext@60724164[app:whatever3000 module:whatever3000.war path:
    spec-version:2.5]] Servlet failed with Exception
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

after which the application is completely defunct with `NoClassDefFoundError` until the app server is restarted.

The full stack trace shows the origin of the issue is a `ConcurrentModificationException` in a static initializer.

Specifically the equivalent / minimized code is as follows:

```
package a;
import b;

public class Whatever {
    void doIt()
    {   
        Password p = new Password();
    }   
}

package b;

public final class Password implements Serializable
{
    private static final int PARAM1 = CommonStuff.someStaticMethod();
    ... 
}

import java.util.Properties;

public class CommonStuff
{
    private static Properties prp = new Properties();

    static {
        CommonStuff.load();
    }   

    public static void load()
    {   
        prp.putAll(System.getProperties()); <---FAIL
```

This is the origin of the Exception:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.Hashtable$Enumerator.next(Hashtable.java:1017)
        at java.util.Hashtable.putAll(Hashtable.java:469)
        at b.CommonStuff.load(CommonStuff.java:55)
        at b.CommonStuff.<clinit>(CommonStuff.java:77)
        at b.Password.<clinit>(Password.java:44)
        at a.doIt(Whatever.java:99)
```

So it seems at some point during the runtime of the application, WebLogic decided to reload classes from `package b` but when the static block runs it finds that the `Properties` object has been modified.

I don't know if it's being called concurrently or if it's being called multiple times. It could be that the `Properties` object is the original instance created when the app loaded fresh the first time and the reloading of `CommonStuff` class is trying to call `putAll()` again.

Would it help if I do:

```
private static Properties prp = null;

static {
    CommonStuff.prp = new Properties();
    CommonStuff.load();
}
```

I cannot just try things blindly because it's in a production app at a huge company. So I'm trying to understand where I'm going wrong and how to property initialize these variables while classes are being reloaded in the middle of the night.

Any ideas?

Could this be a WebLogic ClassLoader issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes/instances cannot access some class's members before this class is initialized. Because of this no one can access newly created `prp` before static constructor returns. Moving `prp` initializer inside on `static {}` block makes no difference. Also "old" `prp` in the "old" `CommonStuff` and "new" `prp` are not connected in any way (because "old" and "new" `CommonStuff` are different classes for JVM). This all make possibility of concurrent modifications of `prp` look pretty weird.

I believe the reason is in another place. Notice the first line of the stack trace: exception is thrown by `Enumerator` of `Hashtable`. Here is the code of the `putAll` method (as in JDK 8, probably didn't change for many years):

```
for (Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> e : t.entrySet())
    put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
```

Here is the `Enumerator` that throws an exception - and it is not `prp`, it is argument's `Enumerator`.

So the exception is related not to `prp` but to `Map` returned by `System.getProperties()`. The reason is that iterating over system properties map is not thread safe. It seems that another thread is modifying it at the same time.

You need to initialize `prp` differently. I think `clone()` is the simplest way.

Comment: This looks like it's probably the cause. Someone else independently had the same diagnosis. I have added clone() and we'll see over the next few weeks if it works. Thanks.